# when I turn off the breaker, light goes out but I still see some voltage with my voltage checker

Tags: electrical, switch, circuit-breaker

there are two switches in the box.  One goes to an inside light the other goes to an outside light.  i turn off the breaker and both lights go out.  when I check with my voltage checker, I don't see anything on the outside light switch but it does light up off and on when I check the inside light switch in the box.   each of these lights are only controlled by one switch.  any suggestion?

Comment: Just what are you using to check he voltage?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unexpected voltage with switch turned off](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/110092/unexpected-voltage-with-switch-turned-off)

Comment: The question I linked to is sort of a "catch all" for these "strange voltage" questions.  Your answer should be in there as this is almost always attributed to "phantom voltage" and can be ruled out with other methods for measuring the voltage.

Comment: I'm using a little battery powered AC voltage detector from Menards

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0):

A simple non contact voltage tester will detect voltage on a deenergized circuit when another live  cable is in close contact, the way non contact sensors work is using the Hall effect. You can prove a similar function by standing under a power line and raising a fluorescent lamp above your head, wow the light glows, not full power but it glows, Hall effect sensors work the same way, you may have a hot wire in close proximity to one that is turned off and well guess what it lights up because of inductive coupling ( this is how transformers work) so yes your tic tester or non contact tester may light up on a dead circuit that is in close proximity to a live circuit. Turn your main breaker off and there will be no voltage unless you live close to a radio station.